# How to display tableview images as soon as they are downloaded rather than after reloading cells

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a table view that displays a list of users. The avatar images in each cell are downloaded asynchronously using UIImageView+AFNetworking and displayed using UIImage+TPAdditions. Here is my code snippet, from cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (cell==nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [[global.people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];


// setImageWithUrl:placeholderImage: is taken from UIImageView+AFNetworking

NSString* imgURL =  [[global.people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]avatar_url];
UIImageView* imgV = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
[imgV setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];

//These are just for formatting and are taken from UIImage+TPAdditions

cell.imageView.image = [imgV.image imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(43,43)];
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```

Now when the app loads we just see the placeholder images until the user scrolls the tableview up and down. Then the avatar images from the URLs are loaded into each cell's image view. I want to make it so that this scrolling is not required- I want the avatar images to "pop" into their respective cells' tableviews as soon as they are downloaded. I know NSNotification might help me, but I'm not really sure where/how to use that. I'm fairly new to iOS. Can anyone walk me through it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to call [setNeedsDisplay](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay) on your view to force a refresh.  You would call this in your asynchronous call's completion handler.